# Remove already existing event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener

I'm trying to remove an already existing event listener from an object. I've tried several methods (using jQuery `.off()`, `.unbind(),` standard `removeEventsListeners()`), but as stated in the docs they can  only remove previously added ones?

Using the Chrome debugger, I can see and remove the specified event listener,
[image]

Also, when trying to list the event listeners via `jQuery _data()` function, it won't list the event. Have been searching for an answer for a couple of hours now.

Can anyone help? Any workaround?

**Edit**: *I have to keep some, so cloning is not possible*.

Comment: Can you add code for how you're trying to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the event handler was added with `addEventListener`, you cannot remove it unless you have a reference to the handler function that was added. I assume that must be the case, because if it were hooked up with jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (or various shortcuts for it), [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) would work, and you've said it didn't work.

One way to work around that is to *replace* the element with a clone. When you clone an element using the DOM's [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode), you *don't* copy its event handlers. So if you start out with `element`, then you can clone it, use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) to insert the clone, then use [`removeChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) to remove the original:

```
var newElement = element.cloneNode(true); // true = deep
element.parentNode.insertBefore(newElement, element);
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Of course, this is indeed a workaround. The proper thing would be not to set up the handler in the first place, or keep a reference to it if you need to be able to remove it later.

---

In a comment you've said you can't do that, and asked:

> Is there a way to add a new event listener that blocks the already existing one?

Only if you can get there **first**, otherwise no, you can't.

You can't add a new handler that blocks an existing one (not in a standard way cross-browser), but if you can add yours before the other one is added, you can prevent it being called by using [`stopImmediatePropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation):

```js
// Your handler
document.getElementById("target").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("Your handler");
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  e.stopPropagation();
});

// The one that you're trying to prevent
document.getElementById("target").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  console.log("Handler you're trying to prevent");
});
```

```html
<div id="target">Click me</div>
```

So for instance, if the other handler is added in the `window` `load` event, or a jQuery `ready` handler, you may be able to get yours in first by putting your code in a `script` tag immediately after the element in question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apperently I have to keep some event listeners, so this is not an option. Is there a (security) reason why we can't access the event listeners as I described? I guess I have to somehow work around my problem. Is there a way to add a new event listener that blocks the already existing one?

Comment: @VanC - I've updated the answer. Unfortunately, unless you can get your handler in there *first*, you can't block the other one. It gets run before yours does (they're run in order).

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I kept the original event and just put one on top, it's ok that both are fired. Most important is that there was a learning process.

Answer (score 1):

A very easy way of doing this is to append nothing to the parent element with .innerHTML. Just be aware this destroys all event listeners that are descendants of the parent element. Here's an example (click 2 to destroy the event listener attached to 1):

```js
const d1 = document.querySelector('#d1');
d1.addEventListener('click', () => console.log(123));

const d2 = document.querySelector('#d2');
d2.addEventListener('click', () => d1.parentNode.innerHTML += '');
```

```html
<div><button id="d1">1</button></div>
<div><button id="d2">2</button></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have to keep some event listeners. I answered T.J. Crowders answer for some more info.

Comment: Nice workaround, still working in 2023